# Running traces across THT footprints

Tags: pcb, kicad, trace, through-hole

Will this work, knowing that I'm running traces across THT footprints?

Kicad lets me do it, but will PCB manufacturers be able to print the board?

On the other hand I had no other choice as I might also want to etch boards myself, so I had to keep it single layer.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "across footprints"? Like running traces between pads/under components? That's perfectly fine and very frequently done--you'd be hard pressed to find a complex professionally-designed board that doesn't.

Comment: I meant like in the picture I posted. Traces run across THT footprints so they'll be running under THT components. Thank for your answer but I'm unsure you understood my question then..

Comment: In that case, yes, this is perfectly normal. Like I said, you'd probably have a hard time finding any boards other than the absolute simplest that don't do this.

Comment: Do you mean a THT pad that has two tracks of the same net emanating from it? That's perfectly normal. If you want to cross a THT pad with a track from a different net, that ought to be not possible in any sane PCB program, and I don't see any on your layout. Running tracks under footprints, that is component bodies, is perhaps the most basic method of getting reasonable component density on a PCB, and is allowed everywhere the component doesn't have a conductive bottom heatsink pad / powerPAD, which if it has will be marked by a very prominent 'keep out' for tracks in the data sheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is perfectly normal to run tracks through THT footprints, and even between IC pins, as long as you leave sufficent clearance between the tracks and component pads.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't made any PCBs for many years but it should be fine - but take the advice of others.

Observations:

- You have the possibility of lining up R9, R1, R2 and R4 on the same Y position with R4 oriented in parallel with R2.
- R5 could also be brought around or at least rotated to be in alignment with the others.
- C1 and C2 can share the same vertical alignment.
- R3 could be brought around to the top and oriented horizontally to match R7, etc.
- I don't know what U1 is but I don't see any sign of a 100 nF decoupling capacitor anywhere.
- Move all the header / jumper pins to the edge of the board. If the pins are in a vertical pattern then the legend should be to the right or left so they're not obscured by adjacent pins.
- The board has no mounting holes (but they may not be required).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is my first Kicad design.

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind a couple of things: 1. Can you make it easy to "stuff" the board (insert components) by keeping orientation the same and in a regular grid? 2. Can you make it easy to troubleshoot? (You have a square pin on U1-1 and U2 so that makes it easy to probe from the underside. Is C5 correct?) 3. Be prepared to have a few goes at layout. Start by placing the components first in a tidy layout, roughly where you think they'll end up. Then try routing. You could for a single-layer layout afford a couple of jumpers but you might find that moving components allows routing.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I will try your suggestions once I'm sure this 'under THT traces' is an option! Yes I had to 'Jump' pin3 as I was surrounded. Also the 100nF cap was not on the schematics I used, where would you place it?

Comment: Beside the supply pins, probably. I used to subscribe to Elektor magazine years ago and they did beautiful PCB layouts. Have a look at https://www.vocoder.eu/detecting-interface.html, for example.

Comment: I could see traces running across THT footprints right away! I'm relieved that it's a possibility, I had no idea after years of making perma-protos to build my instruments and effects at http://cmosorchestra.com. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Transistor, I hope you won't mind me giving the answer to Peter, as you said 'take the advice of other', and Peter's answer was very straightforward. Thanks again

Comment: "*Peter's answer was very straightforward.*" ... and answered the question with some authority - whereas I mostly answered a question that you didn't ask. :^) I think everyone is happy.

Comment: Well I am for sure :). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's fine.

First, copper traces are etched.

Then, green soldermask is applied everywhere except pads. It's a varnish that protects copper traces and prevents solder bridges and shorts.

Then, white silkscreen (basically paint) is applied on top so you can see your component labels. It has no electrical function.

So, traces that pass below the white component outlines (silkscreen) are not a problem at all, they just receive a bit of silkscreen ink on top. Unless:

- The trace carries high voltage (like mains), and you need a specific distance between the trace and components/other pads for isolation/creepage protection.

For example if you use an optocoupler to isolate a part of the circuit from mains, your isolation/creepage distance is the width of the optocoupler. So usually you wouldn't route traces under it, because that would reduce the creepage distance.

For low voltage stuff, no issue at all.

- Or the trace carries high frequency/high amplitude signals and could couple into a the sensitive input of an amplifier.

Some notes:

- You need mounting holes in the 4 corners (pick your favorite screw, measure the head, make a pad with the same diameter as the head, and the hole 0.5mm wider than the screw)
- Label the power supply connector: you can stick some text next to it like "+5V" "GND" next to the appropriate pins.
- In prototype quantity, double sided boards usually cost the same as single sided boards, so go ahead and use both sides! You'll save a lot of time.

Also all your PCB is in red, which means it's on the top layer. If you order a single sided board without plated through holes, you won't be able to solder your components, because you won't have any pads on the bottom. But if you order a double sided board with plated through holes, it's fine.

- Placement:

On the right you have 2 caps and a resistor that only connect to the chip in the middle. If they only connect to the chip, they should be close to the chip. This shortens traces, reduces the number of long traces, and thus the amount of work.

Comment: I wouldn't take the trace colour as necessarily indicating the layer, particularly if you are doing your own PCB etching, as the OP suggests he will do.

Comment: @bobflux Now I'm a bit confused..Should I move all the traces to the B.Cu (blue) layer?

Comment: Normally yes, you'd put them on the bottom layer. If you order a double sided PCB, it doesn't matter which side the traces are on (you could use both). But if you etch a single sided PCB yourself, you need the traces to be on the bottom, otherwise you won't be able to solder your capacitors, because the pads will be hidden under the component. Also make sure it doesn't end up mirrored!